# Tableau "generic" or "service" account?

Tags: administration, tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau and am wondering what the best practice is, if any, for storing Workbooks / Dashboards / Extracts, etc under a "generic" or "service" account:

We have a number of production Workbooks, etc which were all created and stored under our most prolific user's Tableau On-Line account but now that person has left the company and it's not entirely clear to me what we should do with that account and all of the "objects" it owns.

So is there an analog in Tableau On-Line to using, for example, a "www" or "prod" account on our Unix machines to store our crons, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Tableau License Agreement, you can only have named user accounts, so you're not allowed to generic accounts.